# Getting the property from the active slide in MongoDB Ionic React

Tags: reactjs, typescript, ionic-framework, mongodb-realm

I try to show one collection field based on the ObjectId that's related to another collection in MongoDB. I have 3 collections:

Users:

```
{
    "_id" : "115ds1f4sd55fe1e51fds5f4",
    "name" : "Sam",
    "age" : 25
}
```

Country:

```
{
    "_id" : "654564dsf65g4d1e51fds5f4",
    "userId" : ObjectId ("115ds1f4sd55fe1e51fds5f4"),
    "country" : "New Zealand"
}

{
    "_id" : "8247dddsf65g4d1e51fds5f4",
    "userId" : ObjectId ("115ds1f4sd55fe1e51fds5f4"),
    "country" : "Australia"
}
```

Address:

```
{
    "_id" : "6184s68f4se65f4se6d545ee",
    "CountryId" : ObjectId("654564dsf65g4d1e51fds5f4"),
    "userId" : ObjectId ("115ds1f4sd55fe1e51fds5f4"),
    "address" : "12345 Main Street",
    "city" : "Auckaland"
}

{
    "_id" : "6184s68f4se65f4se6d545ee",
    "CountryId" : ObjectId("654564dsf65g4d1e51fds5f4"),
    "userId" : ObjectId ("115ds1f4sd55fe1e51fds5f4"),
    "address" : "12345 Main Street",
    "city" : "Wellington"
}

{
    "_id" : "6184s68f4se65f4se6d545ee",
    "CountryId" : ObjectId("8247dddsf65g4d1e51fds5f4"),
    "userId" : ObjectId ("115ds1f4sd55fe1e51fds5f4"),
    "address" : "12345 Main Street",
    "city" : "Sydney"
}
```

Now on the app that I practice on, I use Swiper Slider Module to display the Country this user lived, now I want to show all the Addresses this user has under the carousel depending on which country is displayed in the Swiper slider.

For example:
If the slider is in Australia, the IonCard only show 1 address in Sydney. If the slider is in New Zealand, the IonCard shows 2 addresses of Auckland & Wellington.

If anyone has any idea that will be awesome!

Here is the function that I use to fetch the country in the swiper slider:

```
useEffect(() => {
        async function fetchCountry() {
            const client = app.currentUser?.mongoClient("mongodb-atlas");
            const collection = client?.db("database").collection("country");
            return collection?.find({ userId: new ObjectId(app.currentUser?.id) });
        }

        if (loadingCountry) {
            fetchCountry().then((r) => {
                setCountry(r);
                setLoadingCountry(false);
            });
        }
    }, [loadingCountry]);
```

And I want to use a similar function to fetch the address as well but not sure how I can retrieve the countryId from the country function.
Here is what I used:

```
return collection?.find({ countryId: new ObjectId("654564dsf65g4d1e51fds5f4") });
```

it will show the address from this countryId however it won't change when the slides change to another country.

Answer (score 0):

I have a feeling you are looking for more than this, can you provide additional information if that is true

```
db.collection.find( { CountryId: { $eq: ObjectId("654564dsf65g4d1e51fds5f4") } } )
```

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/

Comment: Hi Aaron, thank you for the answer! I have added more details of what I did try before and the main thing is to achieve when the slider is on NZ, the IonCard only shows address in NZ, and when the slider is on Australia it will show address in Australia.

Comment: this is still not enough code for me to understand since I only see one query in the code